# Convertir un String array literal a un String array

Tags: java

La cuestión es como Convertir un String array literal a un String array:

```
String arrayLiteral = "[NuevaYork, PepePerez, Troll]"

a String[] array = { "NuevaYork", "PepePerez", "Troll" }
```

Tengo un "**Object"** que solo puedo convertir mediante **Object.toString()** a literal para sacar sus elementos.

Edit:

```
String[] array = arrayLiteral.split(",");
```

Cuando realizas un loop devuelve:

```
        for(String string : array) {
            System.out.println("STRING: " + string);
        }
```

Output:

```
STRING: [NuevaYork
STRING: PepePerez
STRING: Troll]
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, a que te refieres con "La salida a eso es individualmente: 1: [NuevaYork 2: PepePerez 3: Troll]" ? @GuillermoDíazUrbano

Comment: Te respondo en edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes eliminar el primer y último caracter, quedándote con el resto y luego usar split:

```
String[] palabras = arrayLiteral.substring(1,arrayLiteral.length-1).split(", ?");
```

El método split usa una expresión regular, por tanto puedes usar como separador `, ?`, que significa *una coma, opcionalmente seguida de un espacio*.

Comment: Acompañado de un .replaceAll("\\s","") eliminé los espacios y se me quedó perfecto. Gracias. Regex es mi tarea pendiente.

Comment: Creo que no te haría falta, si el "separador" incluye el espacio no debería aparecer en los resultados.

Comment: Cierto. Me comí el espacio. Buena respuesta jefe!

Comment: Algún buen tutorial de Regex?

Comment: Puedes mirar el de [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp). Es para Javascript, con lo que tiene algunas particularidades, pero el 90% es aplicable a cualquier lenguaje de programación

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función `split()` para crear un array a partir de separador ","; cuando es creado el array puedes iterar sobre este para obtener los elementos:

```
      String arrayLiteral = "[NuevaYork, PepePerez, Troll]";
      //Crea un String array.
      String[] myArray = arrayLiteral.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ","").split(",");                                     

      //Imprime elementos contenidos en array
      for(String elemento: myArray){
          System.out.println("elemento: " + elemento);
      }
```

salida:

```
elemento: NuevaYork
elemento: PepePerez
elemento: Troll
```

---

Si deseas obtener un elemento simplemente define el indice del elemento en el array, ejemplo:

```
  System.out.println("primer elemento: " + myArray[0]);
  System.out.println("segundo elemento: " + myArray[1]);
  System.out.println("tercer elemento: " + myArray[2]);
```

salida:

```
primer elemento: NuevaYork
segundo elemento: PepePerez
tercer elemento: Troll
```

Comment: La salida a eso es individualmente: 1: [NuevaYork 2: PepePerez 3: Troll]

Comment: replace("[","") da error

Comment: Como que da error :-, ¿Que error muestra?

Comment: Unclosed bracket.

Comment: Un poco extraño lo que dices si estas realizando esto:           String arrayLiteral = "[NuevaYork, PepePerez, Troll]";
          //Crea un String array.
             String[] myArray = arrayLiteral.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ","").split(","); **Revisa esta [demo en linea](https://ideone.com/NL4u3y)**